# dynamically update html using python

Tags: python, html

Looking for some suggestions on how to dynamically update values in  an HTML file, using Python, before rendering it.

For example, my current approach uses:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Example</title>
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div id="main">
    <article>Article</article>
    <nav>{{user_name}}</nav>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Where `{{user_name}}` is what I am trying to dynamically update before rendering the page.

I am currently using:

```
replacing = {'user_name': 'John Doe'}
def demo():
    with open('index.html', 'r') as html_content:
        h_s = html_content.read()
        for k, v in replacing.items():
            h_s = h_s.replace('{{'+ k +'}}', v)
```

Just wondering if there is a standardized way to do this replacement dynamically without using `{{}}`

Comment: I'd strongly advise using the HTML template library that would be built in your web framework of choice... However, this is not "dynamic", it is just "rendering". Here are the docs on Flask, for example - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: Funnily enough, your syntax is already a valid Jinja2 template.

Comment: https://zetcode.com/python/jinja/

Comment: @OneCricketeer Might be better to just link to the Jinja2 docs, that's what Flask uses.

Comment: Python has [templates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) built in, in addition to [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). But yes, the standard is [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com), [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/) or whatever other templates.

Comment: @AKX It's linked via the Flask docs. But there are more options than Jinja like Mako

Comment: @OneCricketeer But OP might not be doing this in a web framework context at all? Maybe they're just generating a folderful of HTML.

Comment: @AKX you're correct actually! Jinja is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks all who took time to reply